# What is User::create(~) in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I have a question about Laravel, Auth. I tried to check what `User::create(~)` in App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController is but I couldn't find the information. What is it? Where is the source code of that method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `User` model and all the models in Laravel are by default extending the `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` class. The `create` method belongs to `Eloquent\Builder`.

If you want to check the source code, everything is documented [in the Laravel API](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_create):

```php
/**
 * Save a new model and return the instance.
 *
 * @param  array  $attributes
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|$this
 */
public function create(array $attributes = [])
{
    return tap($this->newModelInstance($attributes), function ($instance) {
        $instance->save();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

User is a model. You can find the model in App\User. When you import the model in your Controller, (in this case User) you can make a new instance from the model (wich wel be a new record in your database table users).

Example:

```
User::create([
 'name' => 'Foo',
 'password' => 'azerty',
]);
```

You can find more here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent